# Extracting part of {{ inventory_hostname }} in Ansible to use in a playbook

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm currently writing a small Ansible playbook whose job is to put in an additional domain in the search list in /etc/resolv.conf.

The second domain to add to the search list must contain part of the hostname of the target hosts. I'm getting the hostname of each of the target hosts during playbook execution using the magic variable {{ inventory_hostname }}.

I then need to extract characters 4 - 6 from the {{ inventory_hostname }} (say 'xyz') such that the second domain to add to the search list is xyz.foo.bar. In bash, this would be obtained with something like:

```
SERVER=$('hostname':3:3)
env=${SERVER:3:3}
```

... and the variable 'env' would be equal to 'xyz'.

The playbook works as long as 'xyz' is manually defined.

I am aware that Ansible has regular expression filters which can help with something like this, however I could not figure out a regular expression which does what I need.

For completeness sake, I have tried something like this in ansible:

```
{{ inventory_hostname|3:3 }}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Clifton, welcome to SO. Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61485408/edit) and include what you **have** tried that lead you to not being able to figure out the regex you need; this is not a write-code-for-me website, but we will be glad to help you troubleshoot errors you are experiencing in **your attempt**

Comment: Hello mdaniel, sorry for that. I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

It's almost the same, you can use `"{{ inventory_hostname[3:6] }}"` to select characters 3 to 6.

For example this task

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname[3:6] }}"
```

Will output

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "alh"
}
```

Comment: Hello Paul, that worked! Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me! Much appreciated.